# Set cursor position in Edit Text android

Tags: android-edittext, cursor

How can i set the cursor position in android edit text? Im making a button which would make the cursor one character forward ie. an arrow key like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use setSelection(int position) method of edittext.
Like edt.setSelection(0)

Comment: ok I got it first I would need to get current cursor position and then do setSelection(position+1)

Comment: Yes exactly .get the position and add 1 in that position.Please give me the vote..!!

Answer (score 3):

You can length of the string entered in edit text.

```
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
```